# How can I get P(B|A)?

Tags: probability, distributions

How can I get P(B|A) based on P(A) and P(B)?

Comment: "Is it reasonable to conclude that $P(B\mid A) = P(B)-P(A)$?" What if $P(B)$ were to be smaller than $P(A)$?

Comment: Can you estimate the $P(A\cup B)$? If it is yes, you can obtain the $P(A \cap B)$

Comment: P(B) were larger than P(A). In this case, is it reasonable to conclude that P(B|A) = P(B)-P(A)? I don't know p(A U B).

Comment: The answer is no - it is not reasonable. Also - you need to make your question clearer - a probabilistic event cannot be defined as an area - what exactly are the events A and B?

Comment: I edited my question. Does it make sense? If so, How can I get P(B|A) based on the above numbers and probabilities?

Comment: The editing of the question means that the existing answer no longer makes sense to a new reader. It may have been better to ask "Can I calculate P(A|B) from P(A) and P(B)?" as a new question.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sometimes asking a question takes several kicks at the can, especially until one learns to avoid certain terms or phrases confusingly or that are confusing. Or.... until people learn that someone is not worth arguing with (like me-hah!). Keep trying.

Answer (score 6):

Your events are defined a bit strangely, but if I can cut through the noise, I'm guessing that your scientific question here is:

Given that an apple was vaccinated, how likely is it that it will still rot?

Then, it should be quite clear that you **cannot** determine this probability from just the proportion of apples that were vaccinated and the proportion of apples that have rotten. You need to know **which** apples were vaccinated to know if they **also** rotted away, or not. That's what the intersection means. You can't get what you want unless you have this information, plain and simple.

Aside from that, the difference $P(B)-P(A)$ doesn't mean anything useful at all, and you haven't justified where it could possibly come from.

Comment: Do I need to know number of apples that were vaccinated and also rotted away?

Comment: To answer the question as I posed it, yes.

Comment: The apples that were rotten were vaccinated in the 1/4 of the fruit. Thus, P(B|A) is 0.25. Is it right?